# Comparing two arrays of unequal length

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I have two arrays, say

```
array1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
array2 = {13, 4, 6, 20, 21};
```

I want to compare these two arrays by cycling `array1` through all elements in `array2`. The output should be the position in each array where they match a condition, where the condition `array2[[m]] = array1[[n]]-1` is true. That is, the output should be:

```
output = {6,2}
```

Because in `array2`, $5-1 = 4$. (`array1[[6]] = 5` and `array2[[2]] = 4`). So far, my code is

```
output = {Position[array1, #][[1, 1]], 
 Position[array2, #][[1, 1]]} & /@ (I have no idea)
```

Where the code on the left hand side of Map gives me the positions of a true condition. On the right hand side of Map, I'm not sure what to do.

To clarify a little bit, the code I want is similar to

```
output = {Position[array1, #][[1, 1]], 
Position[array2, #][[1, 1]]} & /@ Intersection[array1, array2]
```

Except I want the position of the element when `array2 = array1-1` instead of when `array1 = array2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) to construct all pairs of positions and use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) to pick the pairs that satisfy your condition:

```
pairs = Tuples[{ Range[Length[array1]], Range[Length[array2]]}];
Select[pairs, array1[[#[[1]]]] - 1 == array2[[#[[2]]]] &]
```

> {{6, 2}, {8, 3}}

You can also use [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) as follows:

```
Join @@ Outer[If[array1[[#]] - 1 == array2[[#2]], {##}, Nothing] &, 
  Range[Length[array1]], Range[Length[array2]]]
```

> {{6, 2}, {8, 3}}

Yet other ways: variations on Roman's method using `Position` and `Outer` combination:

```
Position[1] @ Outer[Subtract, array1, array2] 
Position[True] @ Outer[Equal, array1 - 1, array2] 
Position[{i_, i_}]@Outer[List, array1 - 1, array2]
```

> {{6, 2}, {8, 3}}

Comment: I like your `Outer[Subtract, ...` way!

Comment: thank you @Roman. Didn't think of using `Position` until i saw your answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much! This is really helpful.

Comment: On my machine the `Position[True]@Outer[Equal, array1 - 1, array2]` method performs best.

Answer (score 4):

This is a general solution for any condition between the elements of `array1` and `array2`:

```
Position[Outer[List, array1, array2], {i_, j_} /; j == i - 1]
```

> {{6, 2}, {8, 3}}

@kglr's solutions are simpler than this when the condition is a difference as in the given problem.